# HTML5 RichTextDocuments

Tags: html

I have been looking into HTML 5 and going through tutorials online etc. I Was wondering if there were was something like a Rich Text Document viewer to display, doc, docx, pdf etc?

Or even a tool that converts these document type into html. I googled online and found some websites, but no examples were available. Was hoping someone could recommend a tool or example which is available online..

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

> I Was wondering if there were was something like a Rich Text Document viewer to display, doc, docx, pdf etc?

Nothing generic. It is possible to apply lashings of JavaScript. For example: [pdf.js](http://andreasgal.com/2011/06/15/pdf-js/).

> Or even a tool that converts these document type into html.

There are numerous tools (not the least of which is Microsoft Office itself) that can convert Word documents to HTML.

Comment: Cheers for the input Quentin. I have been trying a few online, some have been pretty good. Any you have had previous experience with you could recommend?